# Get id of Jquery Object (this ) in a js file?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-slider

I am working with [content carousel slider](http://tympanus.net/Development/CircularContentCarousel/).

I am having a js file for the same and I just need to call function from my html file.

Everything runs fine till now. But now I want to use the same slider twice in my page so to avoid conflicts between similar class names which are used by js file to give me a sliding effect,I want to make it specific to the id I would like to pass in a function..Based on that id,I would like to filter out the divs to be affected by js file.

I tried finding how to get id of jQuery window object, I am getting in js file...but no success..

The code is like:

**HTML**:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();// i call function from here   

</script>
```

**JS**

```
   (function($) {

    alert(this.get(0).attr("id")); // gives nothing

    alert($(this).attr("id")); // gives undefined - I got this: logically its a jquery window object so that was obvious... 


    var aux     = {
        // navigates left / right
        navigate    : function( dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache ) {

            var scroll      = opts.scroll,
                factor      = 1,
                idxClicked  = 0;

            if( cache.expanded ) {
                scroll      = 1; // scroll is always 1 in full mode
                factor      = 3; // the width of the expanded item will be 3 times bigger than 1 collapsed item 
                idxClicked  = cache.idxClicked; // the index of the clicked item
            }

            // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
            if( dir === 1 ) {
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', ( cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).appendTo( $wrapper );
                });
            }
            else {
                var $first  = $wrapper.children().eq(0);

                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + ( cache.totalItems  - 1 - scroll ) + ')').each(function(i) {
                    // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', - ( scroll - i + idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).insertBefore( $first );
                });
            }

            // animate the left of each item
            // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this);
                $item.stop().animate({
                    left    :  ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px' : '+=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px'
                }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
                    if( ( dir === 1 && $item.position().left < - idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor ) || ( dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ( ( cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor ) ) ) {
                        // remove the item that was cloned
                        $item.remove();
                    }                       
                    cache.isAnimating   = false;
                });
            });

        },
        // opens an item (animation) -> opens all the others
        openItem    : function( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache ) {
            cache.idxClicked    = $item.index();
            // the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items) 
            cache.winpos        = aux.getWinPos( $item.position().left, cache );
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').not( $item ).hide();
            $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css( 'left', cache.itemW + 'px' ).stop().animate({
                width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px',
                left    : cache.itemW + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
            .end()
            .stop()
            .animate({
                left    : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating   = false;
                cache.expanded      = true;

                aux.openItems( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache );
            });

        },
        // opens all the items
        openItems   : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this),
                    idx     = $item.index();

                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.css( 'left', - ( openedIdx - idx ) * ( cache.itemW * 3 ) + 'px' ).show().find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        left    : cache.itemW + 'px',
                        width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px'
                    });

                    // hide more link
                    aux.toggleMore( $item, false );
                }
            });
        },
        // show / hide the item's more button
        toggleMore  : function( $item, show ) {
            ( show ) ? $item.find('a.ca-more').show() : $item.find('a.ca-more').hide(); 
        },
        // close all the items
        // the current one is animated
        closeItems  : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

            $openedItem.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({
                width   : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
            .end()
            .stop()
            .animate({
                left    : cache.itemW * ( cache.winpos - 1 ) + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating   = false;
                cache.expanded      = false;
            });

            // show more link
            aux.toggleMore( $openedItem, true );

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this),
                    idx     = $item.index();

                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        width   : '0px'
                    })
                    .end()
                    .css( 'left', ( ( cache.winpos - 1 ) - ( openedIdx - idx ) ) * cache.itemW + 'px' )
                    .show();

                    // show more link
                    aux.toggleMore( $item, true );
                }
            });
        },
        // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
        // val is the left of the item
        getWinPos   : function( val, cache ) {
            switch( val ) {
                case 0                  : return 1; break;
                case cache.itemW        : return 2; break;
                case cache.itemW * 2    : return 3; break;
            }
        }
    },
    methods = {
        init        : function( options ) {

            if( this.length ) {

                var settings = {
                    sliderSpeed     : 500,          // speed for the sliding animation
                    sliderEasing    : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the sliding animation
                    itemSpeed       : 500,          // speed for the item animation (open / close)
                    itemEasing      : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the item animation (open / close)
                    scroll          : 1             // number of items to scroll at a time
                };

                return this.each(function() {

                    // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    var $el             = $(this),
                        $wrapper        = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
                        $items          = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
                        cache           = {};

                    // save the with of one item    
                    cache.itemW         = $items.width();
                    // save the number of total items
                    cache.totalItems    = $items.length;

                    // add navigation buttons
                    if( cache.totalItems > 3 )  
                        $el.prepend('<div class="ca-nav"><span class="ca-nav-prev">Previous</span><span class="ca-nav-next">Next</span></div>') 

                    // control the scroll value
                    if( settings.scroll < 1 )
                        settings.scroll = 1;
                    else if( settings.scroll > 3 )
                        settings.scroll = 3;    

                    var $navPrev        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-prev'),
                        $navNext        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-next');

                    // hide the items except the first 3
                    $wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );

                    // the items will have position absolute 
                    // calculate the left of each item
                    $items.each(function(i) {
                        $(this).css({
                            position    : 'absolute',
                            left        : i * cache.itemW + 'px'
                        });
                    });

                    // click to open the item(s)
                    $el.find('a.ca-more').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        $(this).hide();
                        var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.openItem( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        return false;
                    });

                    // click to close the item(s)
                    $el.find('a.ca-close').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.closeItems( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        return false;
                    });

                    // navigate left
                    $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // navigate right
                    $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // adds events to the mouse
                    $el.bind('mousewheel.contentcarousel', function(e, delta) {
                        if(delta > 0) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        else {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        return false;
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    };

$.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel' );
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

please help me finding out how can i call function  with same class names but different ids and on other side,i would be able to filter out the action?

even if there is some other way of achieving my goal,please let me know.i am free either way!!

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more details regarding the js. What are the differences you would like to set between each carousel ? Why not use a class instead of an id, and add some data-* attributes to indicate to your code how to react ?

Comment: actually the classes would be same. i want carousel and there are not difference.just there are two blocks of content..so for them,i need to use slider twice separately. for ex: for product-category one,there are 8 items,and same for category-2...so i need to have slider for both of them separately.

Comment: @CyrilN.: please find the complete js file in my question. hope my above comment is clear to you for what i need.

Comment: I don't understand. If the content is different, it will be different in the dom, and when you initiate the carousel, it will load two different instance based on the content on every dom element you pass to it (when you call `$('#ca-container').contentcarousel();`). So if you add a class like "carousel" in your two elements, and call `$('.carousel').contentcarousel();`, it will load two instances, with the specific content for each dom element.

Comment: Correct you are.. I am beginner in jQuery and didnt' know this fact. Thanks for the information. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `init` method of your JS file, you have a variable `$er` :

```
var $el = $(this)
```

This `$el` is the current element. So, you'll get the `id` of the element directly using :

```
var elementId = $el.attr('id'); // Now, elementId = ca-container
```